# Chinese glue gun small resistance

Tags: ac, heat

So I've bought Chinese glue gun at ebay, but it had incompatible power plug and terrible cable.

I decided to replace wire and plug. I disassembled gun, and saw that wire goes straight to tip (which usually melts glue). But when I took metallic clip which was pressing to place where cable ended, I *suddenly drop* it.

I look what was there: *yellow insulator* (that plastic wrap which is hard to melt), *2 "golden" plates* (connected to wires), and one *metallic plate* (looks like aluminum, sure it's not nichrome).

So looks like that metallic plate should be between "golden" ones. But here is the problem: It has **only 0.07 ohm resistance** when assembled back.
I've thought that original cable has resistance, but then wires should heat more then heater, but i checked anyway -- its 0.

Then I heat tip with solder till it started melting glue to check if resistance increases a lot with heat, but resistance still was very close to 0.

Looks like it's unsafe to use it because it'll be short circuit.

Am I right? Maybe I just assembled it wrong? Should I try to test it?

Photo: [image: Parts]

Comment: Is there a question here? Or is it just a statement?

Comment: @TomCarpenter Forgot the question, but now edited.

Comment: Sounds like you reassembled it wrong. Without decent photos it's going to be hard to give much help.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Added photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know this, but apparently glue guns are made with rectangular** PTC (positive temperature coefficient) elements for the heater. From [this](http://www.ptc-heater.com.tw/PTC_element_eng.htm) source.

[image]

Note that the resistance at room temperature should be **much** higher than you state (probably a couple hundred ohms depending on whether it's for 120 or 240VAC). Check your meter against a known value resistor just to be sure it is working correctly.

** Okay, really a right-angled parallelepiped

Comment: Ok, you are right. I thought that it was just non-metallic compactor, but it was PTC. Now it 8.5k ohms, much better